# Autocomplete not working in data-toggle twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to use autocomplete for a textbox in data-toggle and found that the auto complete is not working for me in the data-toggle view, but working before data-toggle.

```
    ....
    ....
    ....
<!--this is data-toggle caller-->
    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="padding:5px 10px;margin-left:50px;" > <span class=" fa fa-paper-plane-o fa-lg" > </span> Proceed to checkout </button>
    ....
    ....
    ....
<!--this is data-toggle caller-->
    <div id="myModal" ....>
    ....
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete-custom-append" class="form-control col-md-10" style="float: left;" />
                            <div id="autocomplete-container"></div>
                          </div>
    ....
    </div>
```

and this is the jquery and js imports used

```
<!-- Autocomplete -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/autocomplete/countries.js"></script>
  <script src="js/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
  <!-- pace -->
  <script src="js/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      'use strict';
      var countriesArray = $.map(countries, function(value, key) {
        return {
          value: value,
          data: key
        };
      });
      // Initialize autocomplete with custom appendTo:
      $('#autocomplete-custom-append').autocomplete({
        lookup: countriesArray,
        appendTo: '#autocomplete-container'
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: provide your jquery / javascript code

Comment: the update has jquery code..

Comment: its worked used the same id twice...